# Detecting dirty using winforms data binding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding

I am using 2 way binding with winforms text boxes.
I need to work out if the user has changed my data
Looking at the help for

[the CurrentItemChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.currentitemchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

It seems that this event does fire if a property has changed, however it also fires if current has changed.

Is there a way to tell whether the data has changed?

[a similar question is also asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206140/how-to-tell-if-user-has-modified-data-using-bindingsource)
but not answered in my opinion

Oliver mentions "if your object within the List support the INotifyPropertyChanged event and you replace the List by a BindingList you can subscribe to the ListChanged event of the BindingList to get informed about any changes made by the user."

My application meets these conditions but I cant get this working. The ListChangedType.ItemChanged property looked hopeful, but it changes when I navigate to the next record without changing the data

I found a link [at Microsoft here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8334a2f0-ceaf-4183-bf2d-421556d44914/bindingsource-detail-view-is-current-record-dirty?forum=winformsdatacontrols) but surely it cant be that hard!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
void bindingSource_BindingComplete(object sender, BindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.BindingCompleteContext == BindingCompleteContext.DataSourceUpdate)
            {
                var person = (Person)bindingSource.Current;

                if ( person.State == State.Unchanged && (e.BindingCompleteState == BindingCompleteState.Success)
                && e.Binding.Control.Focused)
                {
                    person.State = State.Modified;  // using Julie Lerman's repositories technique
                }
            }
        }
```